# Change Spring Batch Control Table Locking Strategy

Tags: sql-server, spring-batch, database-deadlocks

We have a system that allows an operator to stop a long running Spring Batch job by using the `JobExplorer` to get a reference to the `JobExecution` and calling `stop()` on it. We then have code inside our jobs that use the `JobExplorer` to get an up-to-date copy of the `JobExecution` to check to see if it has been marked as STOPPING.

Our problem is deadlocks on the metadata tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Each select is doing a shared page lock. Everything I have been able to find about changing the lock level talks about using a hint on the `SELECT` statement. But Spring Batch is creating the statement, not our code.

Is there a way to tell Spring Batch to use read-only concurrency when making `SELECT` statements? If not, is there some mechanism short of writing our own `JobExplorer` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> stop a long running Spring Batch job by using the JobExplorer to get a reference to the JobExecution and calling stop() on it.

`JobExecution#stop` will be deprecated in the next minor version 4.3 and removed in the next major version (See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1605). The correct way to stop a job execution is to use `JobOperator#stop`.

> Is there a way to tell Spring Batch to use read-only concurrency when making SELECT statements? If not, is there some mechanism short of writing our own JobExplorer to accomplish this?

There is an open issue to make the job explorer transactional (read-only): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1307. In the mean time, you can make the `SimpleJobExplorer` transactional (either through AOP or by extending it to add `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on methods).

Comment: I must not be understanding what you mean by "extending SimpleJobExplorer to add @Transactional(readOnly=true)". I subclassed it and created it in my subclass of DefaultBatchConfigurer. That all seemed to work right, and my over-ridden methods with the annotation were being called, but all they did was call their super equivalents. No joy.

My JobRepository already has ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED, so I'm out of ideas I can implement. Is it required that my MSSQL database have ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON to get this working?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, decorate the SimpleJobExplorer methods with a transactional advice. That said, I don't see the relation with the isolation level of the job repository. JobRepository and JobExplorer can be configured differently, each one with its own transaction attributes.